# Disk partition errors after size change

Tags: linux, boot, mount, grub, fstab

I increased the disk size of one of my VM when it was running. After a reboot, I get the following error message (at boot time):

Mounting local filesystems...failed
Now the VM is only accessible through ESX console (not through ssh), and nothing is working anymore....

I already tried to run fsck, but without success.

The result of mount:
[image]

The result of blkid:

[image]

The result of fstab:

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please tell me which boot loader you use? Grub, lilo? Also, can you mount this partition and use it's content? I think your problem is not related to partition itself, more to fstab etc - ie in your fstab partitions are addressed by UUID, not by /dev, if for some reason UUID of this partition has changed during size change, it will no longer fit fstab description.

Comment: I'm using grub. I managed to mount the partition by adding a new line to fstab. However, it is now displayed as a duplicate...

Comment: EDIT: Or wait... those UUIDs looks ok. But still, for me this partition is OK. Problem is - it can't be found for some reason. Which distro is it?

Comment: Can you also please elaborate on "nothing is working anymore"?

Comment: Can you try to boot your system passing manually root option to the kernel? In grub, you have to hit `C` key - it will open CLI. Type `linux root=/dev/sda1`. If I'm right, it will point properly kernel to the root partition and system will boot successfully. Fingers crossed :)

Comment: I tried your command, but I got an "invalid file name `root=/dev/sda1`". I'm using a debian 2.6.32